# Invalid URI: The URI is empty error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When initially an Exposure is raised through our sharepoint 2010 web application an email will be sent to the customer with URL to access the page and Approve the Exposure.

If Customer does not approve within 15 days, an another email will be triggered from an emailtimer job scheduled in Sharepoint 2010.

The URL sent to Customer in email should have full application URL in both the cases.

Currently, the mail sent through application has the URL as "http://localhost/pages/exposure.aspx?req=1"

However, through the job I get an error " Invalid URI: The URI is empty".

How do I achieve to have the correct URLs in both the cases. Please help.

My code looks like this.

```
string webUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
string awebUrl = "/pages/Exposures.aspx";
SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl);
string obsoluteUrl = site.MakeFullUrl(awebUrl);
                    objRepeatingTokenList.Add(ExposureEmailTemplateTokenName.TokenExposureURL, string.Format("{0}?mode=View&RequestId={1}",obsoluteUrl , requestId));
```

Comment: Can somebody help me with the solution..thanks so much..

Comment: For starters are your certain "localhost" is correct - perhaps it should be your sharepoint server.